# Raster sampling using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, resampling

Is there an ArcGIS function to sample x% where x lies between 0 and 100, of a raster?

I do not want point sampling and ArcGIS functions seem to focus on point sampling.

For ArcGIS, I use version 10.2

--EDIT: Desired output: This output raster will have x% of cells selected randomly

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you have in mind as "raster sampling". Do you mean raster resampling? Do you want statistics on raster cell values within polygons?

Comment: What's your desired output, a vector of values from the sampled cells?

Comment: no, I just want a raster as output. This output raster will have x% of cells selected randomly

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested following on raster called "DEM", which has 79540 cells with data and a lot of cells with NO DATA:

```
arcpy.CreateRandomRaster_management("../SCRATCH", INT_R", "UNIFORM 0.0 1.0")
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('Con("INT_R" <= 0.50,"DEM")',"..SCRATCH/percent")
```

Output raster has 39955 cells with data. The ratio 39955/79540 = 0.502, i.e. result contains 50% of cells from original raster